# Accessing resources after extracting into a .jar. Works in eclipse but not after extracting

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

So I'm working on a game, more so just to learn the language better by doing something interesting, and in eclipse everything works well. To load images (texures) in eclipse I use this line.

```
this.image = ImageIO.read(new File("./resources/textures/" + fileName + ".png"));
```

Which works perfectly fine in eclipse. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJsay.jpg)

But after exporting it, None of the the textures show up. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni49T.jpg)

The resources folder is inside the .jar, and the textures are in the folder.

I have also tired using this line of code, but it wont load textures in eclipse or the .jar.

```
this.image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("resources/textures/"+fileName + ".png"));
```

Thank you for the help before hand, any suggestions would help! If you need anything else. Just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`getResource()` from `Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), the path is expected to be relative to the class if it is not prefixed with "/". However if you do prefix your path with "/", it indicates to look for the resource from the root of the classpath which is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry If I'm missing something, but, what from what I understand, you're saying that If i put the / there it should fix it, correct? If so, I tried 

`this.image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/textures/"+fileName + ".png"));`

and I still have the same issue. Well not the same issue, it is a different one. It gives me a compile error. 

`Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at me.mbektic.game.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:29)`

Comment: Are the images you are trying to load in your jar? If they are not bundled as resources in your jar, that would explain why they are not found on the classpath while they are found in eclipse when you use a path relative to your working directory ("./")

Comment: Yes I've made sure of that. http://i.imgur.com/aHtvg80.png There's a picture of what the inside of the .jar looks like. Sorry for the late reply, I have not been on my computer since yesterday.

Comment: Your picture proves that you have a `resources` folder in your jar, but not that the files your are trying to access are indeed in the `/resources/textures/` folder...

Comment: I mean, I obviously checked to see if the .pngs are there.

Comment: After reading the documentation for `getResource` once more, I believe I did a faulty assumption where a path preceded with "/" would mean a path from the root of the class classloader, not from the root of the filesystem. Could you try `this.image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/textures/"+fileName + ".png"));`? If this works, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: `this.image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/tex‌​tures/"+‌​fileName + ".png"));` Gives me a complie error. "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens." Any clue?

Comment: I am sorry to tell you I don't have any clue as the exact same code works fine for me in Eclipse Mars using Java 8.

Comment: Okay, so somehow I fixed the syntax issue, (I don't know what was wrong) but now its giving me input == null!. what should I change my path to? `this.image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/textures/" + fileName + ".png"));` Is what I currently have.

Comment: Is it giving you the same result both in Eclipse and when started as a jar? If it works fine when started as a jar, you might need to configure your project classpath in Eclipse to make sure the "resources" directory is being picked up by the ClassLoader.

Comment: it gives me the same result on eclipse and the jar. Eclipse is what tells me that the input is null.

Comment: Have you made sure the resources directory is being picked up by the ClassLoader? Check your project Build Path (in Eclipse, right-click on your project, "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path...") and make sure there is a reference to the resource directory of your project or its parent.

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply, have been very busy with school. But I added the folder under source. However it still gives me the input == null!  error.

Comment: Could you post an image of your "Build path" and another one representing your project structure?